# How to convert string to Array in php

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this in variable

```
var_dump($values)

string(191) "array( 'choices' => array( 'm' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female' ), 'required' => false, 'empty_value' => 'Choose your gender', 'empty_data' => null )"
```

How can I convert this to be arrays?

I tried this

```
$farray = is_array($farray)?$farray:[$farray]
```

and then var_dump gives this

```
> array(1) { [0] => string(191) "array( 'choices' => array( 'm' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female' ), 'required' => false, 'empty_value' => 'Choose your gender', 'empty_data' => null )" } `
```

UPDATE:

I am passing this in annotation in php class and then reading it

```
 * @Type(options="array(
    'choices' => array(
        'm' => 'Male',
        'f' => 'Female'
    ),
    'required'    => false,
    'empty_value' => 'Choose your gender',
    'empty_data'  => null
)"
```

Comment: `$values` is already an array not string

Comment: @user3147180 Please show where does the `$values` come from.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is **How did you get the `$values`**?

Get the array from the source where you get `$values`.

`eval` will give you the result, **but it should be avoid in most case.**

```
$arr = eval('return '.$values.';');
```

Edit:

Since you are trying to parse the annotation, I suggest that use a annotation parse library.
For example:  [Doctrine Annotations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-common/en/latest/reference/annotations.html).

Comment: From PHP manual: "eval() returns NULL unless return is called in the evaluated code". Correct code would be `$arr = eval('return ' . $values);`

Comment: @Jojo Yep, you are right, and an `;` is also necessary.

Comment: @xdazz , if you say that eval should be avoided , is there any better way to convert string arrays to php arrays. i have seen that i can't pass array directly to annottaions , i have send them as strings

Answer (score 0):

Of course, this is string:

```
$string = "array( 'choices' => array( 'm' => 'Male', 'f' => 'Female' ), 'required' => false, 'empty_value' => 'Choose your gender', 'empty_data' => null )";
```

If you want array, you have to declare it without quotes:

```
$array = array('choices' => ...);
```

Comment: I have edited the question, if i just type array then i get error